# CYK algorithm top down design with memoization

Tags: c++, algorithm, cyk

I run the CYK algorithm, however, I am trying to do it as a top down design (memoization), any help?

```
bool canDerive(nonterminal S, string w) {
    return canDeriveRec(S, w, 0, w.size());
}

/* Can you derive the substring [start, end) of w from S? */
bool canDeriveRec(nonterminal S, string w, int start, int end) {
    /* Base case: Single characters */
    if (end - start == 1) {
        return whether there is a production S -> a, where a = w[start];
    }

    /* Recursive case: Try all possible splits */
    for (each production S -> AB) {
        for (int mid = start + 1; mid < end; mid++) {
            if (canDeriveRec(A, w, start, mid) &&
                canDeriveRec(B, w, mid, end)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There's no memoization yet, but that's easy to add. In any case, what are asking for help with?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am trying to add the memoization with a top down design, could you please help me with that?

Comment: @harold any help?

Comment: Just add an unordered map with the right key, no big deal.

Comment: @harold  what do you mean by that? Could you please submit an answer?